# Is there a ways I can add background image to JPanel without using JLabel or Overriding paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing, background, jpanel

I want to add background image to JPanel without using JLabel or overriding paintComponent.

JPanel don't have setIcon(ImageIcon). I really want to dynamically change the background image of JPanel like setIcon in other component like JLabel.

Comment: Then simply use a `JLabel` as the container, specify some `Layout` for it and add components to it. Then use `label.setIcon(randomIcon)`, for random images as backgrounds.

Comment: Any specific reason, for the approach, you have in mind. Clarifying the need, will help us understand the situation in a much better way

Comment: nIcE cOw, you are correct. that is the approach I really want. Thanks

Comment: I have created one [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tf9iqgob1i8f4f6/ImageTest.java?dl=0), since yesterday, regarding the same, but never posted it, since just waiting for a small response, from your side, to know the requirements in a better way :-)

Answer (score 1):

> "I want to add background image to JPanel without using JLabel or overriding paintComponent"

Seems like a bit of a stretch. You want to do something, but you don't to do it the way it's supposed to be done. Maybe a better understanding of how this can be accomplished will make you change your mind.

**JPanel and override paintComponent**

Have a method to `setImage(Image image)` or you can use `ImageIcon`, up to you. You can set the image that is used to paint the background.

```
public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {
    private Image image;

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0 getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
}
```

When you call `setImage` passing it an image, it will dynamically change the image, because of the call to `repaint()`

**Using JLabel**

As nIcE cOw mentioned, you can use the JLabel as the container, and add all your components to the label. Remember JLabel is a subclass of Container. Any Container can be added to. Just keep in mind that JLabel has no layout manager (unlike JFrame and JPanel which has defaults), so you need to set it. You could simply do something like

```
JLabel backgroundLabel = new JLabel();
backgroundLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("backgound.png"));
backgroundLabel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
backgroundLabel.add(new JButton("Hello World"));
```

That's perfectly legal.

**Another Alternative**

A class from Sir Rob Camick [`BackgroundPanel`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/). Check out the link for how to use it. It's basically the same concept as the first option I described, just 100 times better with a whole lot more goodies.

Comment: I am asking for another way, comment by n1ce cOw has the approach I want.